# mysql c++ connector error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: c++, mysql-connector

The error is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_mysql_init", referenced from:
      _main in dao-8fe5b4.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

when I tried to compile the cpp file using the following command.

```
g++ -o test_install   -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/cppconn -L/usr/local/lib dao.cc
```

The dao.cc file is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>

using namespace std;

int
main() {
    MYSQL mysql;
    mysql_init(&mysql);
    return 0;
}
```

When I do not call mysql_init function, there is no error. So the "include" procedure is correct.

The header files are in /usr/local/inclulde and /usr/local/cppconn, and in /usr/local/lib, the lib files are:

```
libmysqlclient.18.dylib        libmysqlcppconn-static.a
libmysqlclient.a               libmysqlcppconn.7.1.1.6.dylib
libmysqlclient.dylib           libmysqlcppconn.7.dylib
libmysqlclient_r.18.dylib      libmysqlcppconn.dylib
libmysqlclient_r.a             libmysqld.a
libmysqlclient_r.dylib         libmysqlservices.a
```

But why it can not link to the functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually *link* with the MySQL library. Add the option `-lmysqlclient` *last* on the command line.